# Why creating a float32 array from a list raises value error?

Tags: python, numpy, valueerror

I'm trying to create a float32 array as follows,

`np.float32([kp2, kp2+dir_v*dist, kp2 + dir_v_r*dist])`

However, I'm getting the following error,

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

I tried to cast it to numpy array explicitly as follows and retry but still, I'm getting the same error

`np.array([kp2, kp2+dir_v*dist, kp2 + dir_v_r*dist]).astype(float)`

what am I missing?

Comment: Why is this tagged C#?  This looks like python code.

Comment: What does `np.array(...)` without the astype produce? Tell us about the elements of the list.

Comment: What are `kp2`, `dir_v`, and `dist`?  It will be easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please share the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the datatype with the `dtype` argument to `np.array()`.

```
np.array([kp2, kp2+dir_v*dist, kp2 + dir_v_r*dist], dtype=float)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that produces your error:

```
In [910]: np.array([1,[1,2,3],4])                                                              
Out[910]: array([1, list([1, 2, 3]), 4], dtype=object)
```

fine without the `float` conversion - but then the error:

```
In [911]: np.array([1,[1,2,3],4]).astype(float)                                                
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-911-9c007059d6ad> in <module>
----> 1 np.array([1,[1,2,3],4]).astype(float)

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I suspect `[kp2, kp2+dir_v*dist, kp2 + dir_v_r*dist]` contains a mix of numbers, arrays, lists that produces an object dtype array.

If the list does contain a mix of numbers and lists of numbers (or arrays), `hstack` might be what you want:

```
In [922]: np.hstack([1,[1,2,3],4])                                                             
Out[922]: array([1, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```